# Multiple client server in which a client can only send message to server but server to all clients in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want that message sent by server should be delivered to all the clients however a message sent by by client should only be delivered to server.

Problem is when i run the code-
1.Server waits for client to connect 
2.when multiple client connected
3.Now as the  server broadcast  the first message it is received by both the clients but when server broadcast the message second time. Both the clients has to send message in order to receive server message. 
I am a noob in socket programming so please correct me what i am doing wrong?
So far i have made this program.

Server Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Server_Side3 
{

 static  Client_server t[] = new Client_server[10];

static LinkedList<Client_server> al = new  LinkedList<Client_server>();



public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {   
    ServerSocket server = null ;
     Socket socket = null;


    try 
    {

        int Port =9777;

        server = new ServerSocket(Port);

        System.out.println("Waiting for Client " + server);

    while(true)
    {

        socket = server.accept();

    System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());

            Client_server clients = new Client_server(socket);

            al.add(clients);


            clients.start();


        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("An error occured."); 
        e.printStackTrace();

    }   

    try
    {
        server.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

private static class Client_server extends Thread
{
    Socket sockets;
    PrintWriter out;

    Client_server t[];  

    Client_server (Socket s )
    {
        sockets = s;
    }

    public void run()
    {

        try
        {       

            InetAddress localaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            Scanner in = new Scanner(sockets.getInputStream());

             out = new PrintWriter(sockets.getOutputStream(),true);


             String input = null;

            while(true)
            {


                String servermsg = sc.nextLine();

                broadcast(servermsg);

                System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+servermsg);



                    input = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(localaddr.getHostName()+" Said :"+ input);




                }



            } 


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

    }

    private   void broadcast(String servermsg)
    {
        Iterator it = al.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            ((Client_server) it.next()).send(servermsg);
        }

    }


    private  void send(String msg)
    {
        String servrmsg = msg;
        out.println(msg);
        out.flush();
    }

   }


  }
```

Client Code :

```
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.util.Scanner;

   public class ClientSide2 
   {

static Scanner chat = new Scanner(System.in);                             



public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int Port = 9777;
    String Host = "localhost";




    try 
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(Host, Port);
        System.out.println("You connected to "+ Host);

      Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());  //GET THE CLIENTS INPUT STREAM 

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        String clientinput;

        while(true)                                                        
        {       


    System.out.println(in.nextLine());//If server has sent us something .Print it       


                clientinput=chat.nextLine();                 
                out.println(clientinput);               //SEND IT TO THE SERVER
                out.flush(); 





         }




    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("The server might not be up at this time.");
        System.out.println("Please try again later.");  
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: multicast is what you are looking for.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: Can't i perform it using  tcp ? Is it necessary to use Datagram ?

Comment: UDP is unreliable(packet loss), tcp is the way to go that it make sure that messages are sent in-order.